# Editor script in VStudio cannot 'see' main scripts

Tags: unity, visual-studio

*(Notice: This is a crosspost with r/UnityHelp)*

When loading a custom editor script into VStudio, it cannot see the main game scripts. This is quite annoying for writing code, as you'll imagine.

Strangely, this is unique to one project - and that project has a particular quirk.

When loading a 'normal' class into VStudio, and I look at the assemblies, I see this:

[image: ONE ASSEMBLY]

Notice how it is only connected to a single assembly.

Compare this to a working project, and I see this:

[image: TWO ASSEMBLIES]

This has two assemblies loaded - .Player and the root assembly.

Looking in the definition of Assembly-CSharp-Editor, it ONLY looks at the root assembly, and not the .Player assembly. If I add it, however, it is of course immediately overridden.

I don't know what I did to cause this, exactly, but I cannot find any material difference in the settings between the projects.

Can anyone please assist in helping to solve this? Thank you.